# Best book for learning information security

Tags: operating-systems, professional-education

What is the best book(s) on the market right now for mastering network security. In other words, what are the best materials out right now to learn hacking/protecting operating systems and software.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Cody. Unfortunately this kind of question is considered off topic here, as it quickly gets out of date.

Comment: Also what is considered best is subjective and depends also on the kind of previous knowledge and experience. And your objective what these books should teach is very broad while at the same time it is unclear how much depth in knowledge you expect to get from these sources.

Comment: Ok. I guess more specifically I am concerned with learning the tools on Kali Linux. Should I continue to ask questions in here in regards to Kali or is there a better place to ask such questions?

Comment: Generally you can say you don´t really need a book to learn such a thing. The best way is to think about what you want to do and google it. You find tons of information about it. If you want to learn "Hacking" or such things check root-me.org out. There are much of examples from beginners to pros. It´s quite funny and helps you to understand the basics of Information Security.

Comment: @CodyRutscher: your question so far tend to be broad, i.e. want to know all ways a phone could be hacked and all the tools etc. I think you should should focus on smaller problems first.

Comment: I hear where you are coming from, but I don't think that it is too broad to ask about the phone number/IMEI hacking software. There has to be someone in this group that can point me in the right direction for this type of software. I understand it is not super specific, but it is also not that broad in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You are traversing the areas of Network Security to Information Security to Application protection to OS protection.
While all those areas are connected and interdependent Network Security and its protocol stack has its own challenges different from the Application security with secure architecture and coding and the OS protection and hardening.
Start with the books for the study for the (ISC)2 CISSP, Computer Networks 5th By Andrew S. Tanenbaum, 
Web Application Security, A Beginner's Guide 1st Edition by Bryan Sullivan, Vincent Liu. There is an endless row of book in the realm of web application hacking. LMGTFY